# AutoHotKey - Disable Script in Specific Application

Tags: autohotkey

I created an ahk script with a keyboard shortcut. However, I would like to disable the shortcut in a specific application. How would I go about doing that? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use under your shortcut command:

```
if WinActive("APPLICATIONNAME")
    return
```

[Documentation here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm)

Comment: [`#IfWin[Not]Active`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm), as mentioned in @Oleg's comment, is the better choice.